# Connecting two dimmers in one box

Tags: wiring

I am replacing one 3 way switch with a dimmer and an older dial dimmer with a new one way pole dimmer.

After powering down and removing the old switch and dial dimmer I found a red wire and two black wires coming from the house to the left and only two black wires coming from the house on the right side where the dial dimmer was. Between the two there was a piece of white wire acting as a bridge between the two sides. It came from one of the right side black wires and connected to the old switch at the top brass screw.

I installed the left side 3-way dimmer according to instructions with no problem...black to the black common wire, then red to red and red/white to the second black wire from the house. Then I installed the single pole dimmer using the two black wires on the right side...Black from the dimmer to the black from the house and the red from the dimmer to the other black wire from the house. The red/white wire from the new dimmer was capped off since it would act as a single pole.

I then connected the small piece of white wire between the black wire on the single side to the hot wire on the 3-way side. End result...everything worked...well, sort of.

The dimmers both worked but, would take turns as to when they would activate. I would slide the kitchen 3-way and the kitchen would dim. Then when I did the single pole for the dinning area it wouldn't work. Then I would try the dining area and it would work but, the kitchen wouldn't. What would be the proper way to have these side by side dimmers work properly?

---

Thanks for the quick reply's.  Here is a picture of the box from the house. The right side is the 3 way to dim the kitchen and share a switch and the left is the one way that only controls the dimming for the immediate dining area. The larger tag has been identified as the hot wire and the other with tape around it is the common wire.  [image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all boxes involved please?

Comment: Sounds like you have mis-identified the power feed, which is what should be what is going to both dimmers, not through one to the other. All black wires are not the same ;-) Try swapping the black wires on the single side, first guess.